# Automating pandas dataframe join from list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of 4 dataframes each containing only 1 column ('CustomerID'). I would like to merge (inner join) them within a loop.

This is what I've try for the moment:

```
for i in all_df:
    merged = all_df[0].merge(all_df[1], on='CustomerID')
    del df[0]
```

What I'm trying to do here is to merge the first dataframe (index 0) with the second (index 1), then delete the first dataframe in order that the dataframe of index 1 becomes the dataframe of index 0 and thus, I could iterate.

I know this doesn't work as what I should merge from the second iteration should be the datframe from the new variable "merged" with the daframe of index 1.

The 4 dataframes are a client database at diferent time (march 2019, april 2019, may 2019 etc.). The point is to analyse the client lifetime (how long did they stay client?, after how many days did they left? etc.)

Could you please help me with that?

Comment: what is your expected output? you want an inner or outer merge?

Comment: What do you mean by "merge" if you only have just one column per DF?

Comment: I think your logic is flawed: in fact even though you could eleminate the first element, then you merge the second with the third in the second iteration, yet you are not using the join obtained during the first time you iterate.

Comment: @AndyL. I've edited my question

Comment: I am still not sure whether `merge` is the right solution for your issue. The 1-column dataframes merging sounds weird to me, but I can't answer definitely without knowing you sample data and expected output. On your question, when you want to join/merge multiple dataframes, use either `merge` with `functools.reduce` or `df.join`.

Comment: I posted an answer using `functools.reduce`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to merge multiple dataframes, you may use `functools.reduce` as follows

```
from functools import reduce
df_merge = reduce(lambda df_x, df_y: pd.merge(df_x, df_y, on='CustomerID'), all_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following your step this should accomplish what you are trying to do:

```
#Initialize the final dataframe
result_df = all_df[0]

# Cycle over the list, from the second dataframe onwards
for df in all_df[1:]:
    result_df = result_df.merge(df, on='CustomerID')
```

Comment: This gives me this error: "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not DataFrame". Should we use something like for i in range(all_df[1:]) ?